# In the current adventures for the campaign settings, is there a mission about carrying out an Assassination?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

In the current adventures for the campaign settings, is there a mission about carrying out an Assassination?

Hi there, **I am looking for an Assassination storyline** for the party and wonder if there is one in the current **official** published adventures for 5e.

This post was helpful to create a Homebrew version:
[How do I design an assassination mission, that is a challenge for the rogue, but not impossible for the other party members and requires teamwork?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100682/how-do-i-design-an-assassination-mission-that-is-a-challenge-for-the-rogue-but)

To clarify, I'm looking for an Assassination storyline where the party's mission or part of the story line is to **find and assassinate** a creature.

Comment: Are you simply asking if they exist in official or DMsguild materials? We can answer that, but that may not be what you actually want. If you want a recommendation, then this is off-topic, but may actually be more helpful to your end need.

Comment: Presently there are three settings with WoTC-published adventures. The Forgotten Realms, Barovia, and Greyhawk. Most of them are in the Forgotten Realms, though; is this the setting you are most interested in?

Comment: When you say "assassinate" a creature, does the mission have to be centered around stealth and the like. I ask because most adventures involve at least one mission that are "find and kill this thing".

Comment: There isn't an official first-party 5E module that centers around "finding and assassinating a creature", however you could look towards older modules if you don't want to use third-party / homebrew content.

Answer (score 1):

It's not officially an assassination, but in Baldur's Gate Descent Into Avernus, one of the early encounters has you meeting a Pirate named Tarina.  She wants your help to kill her former shipmates who are after her.  You can easily rework this into an assassination storyline.
Later, Mortlock Vanthampur urges the characters to capture or kill his brother Amrik.

Comment: Welcome and thanks. That's a great idea. Do you have the page numbers to reference the materials? - regarding meeting Tarina and later Mortlock. It would to add in the answer.